# RabbitMQ is sending the request again if response is null

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

I am using RabbitMq with masstransit for messaging between different services, let us say that we have the following scenario:

First service asks about specific info from second service by sending a request.

Second service looks for the info in database and respond with an object containing the found info.

In case there is no info available in database, the second service responds with a null object.

The issue is that RabbitMQ is considering that the request has failed thus it keeps sending the request again.

Can I configure the bus to consider the null reponse as a normal response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reply with null object. You have two options:

1. Add a boolean property to your response indicating it is not a success
2. Throwing an exception in the request consumer, then the fault message will be sent to the request client.